# Winston js. My log files aren't rotating after exceeding maxsize

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I have the following winston configuration:

```
'use strict'

import winston from 'winston'
import config from '../../config/environment'

export default winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.printf(info => info.message),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: `${config.logsPath}/express.error.log`,
      maxsize: 300,
      level: 'error'
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: `${config.logsPath}/express.log`,
      maxsize: 300
    })]
})
```

None of this files are rotating after they reach the 300 bytes threshold.

Comment: did you check to see the process actually has write permission to create the new logfiles?

Comment: Why would it have permission to create log files initially but not rotate them?
I don't mean to be rude, sorry. Its just that its creating the files when it needs to log. Its just not rotating them.

Comment: well if the files would have been created previously, would have been created manually, copied, via a `touch` command by the logged in user....just an idea on what could be the problem, that's why it's just a comment :)

Comment: Yup. I wish that was the case, but the same process that creates the files is the one responsible for their rotation. I asked in the winstonjs github as an issue but got no reply. I found other user with the same issue though.

Comment: Can you create a sample file which logs info in loop using this logger and and see if any rotation happens then? Else put a breakpoint at https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/19f170a69d19c0d2e16075cf38eca92437775be7/lib/winston/transports/file.js#L354 and see if there is something wrong when you run the code

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot. Tried the loop thing, but not setting the break point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the version `3.0.0` release candidate which has a bug in its `File` transport. Basically, once over the `maxsize` threshold, internal `self.filename` variable was not being updated so `_createStream` would re-open the append stream to the existing file and continue writing to it. It works the first time around because `self.filename` is set when initializing from options.

I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/1109) which fixes the issue. Alternatively, you can revert to `2.4.0` where this isn't an issue.